# Do projections (onto quotients by a closed subspace) have continuous right-inverses?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed vector space and $W\subset V$ be a closed subspace.
Does the projection $\pi\colon V\to V/W$ have a linear continuous right-inverse $R\colon V/W\to V$, i.e. $\pi R=\text{Id}_{V/W}$ ?

A linear right-inverse always exists. Furthermore, a linear continuous right-inverse exists, for example, when $W$ is complemented. In this case $V=W\oplus U$ and $V/W\simeq U$ for a closed subspace $U$, and we can choose $R\colon V/W\stackrel{\sim}{\to} U\to V$.

I wonder if being complemented, or a weaker condition, is necessary.

Comment: Are you intentionally not assuming $V$ to be complete?

Comment: Yes, kind of, see below PhoemueX's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I just realized that you do not require $V$ to be complete (is this intentional?). In this case, my argument below breaks down ($U$ is not necessarily closed). But if $V$ is complete, then my argument shows that $W$ has to be complemented. For incomplete $V$, I am currently looking for a counterexample.

---

It **is** indeed necessary that $W$ is complemented. To see this, first note
$$
\Vert x \Vert =\Vert \pi R x \Vert \leq \Vert Rx \Vert \,\,\forall x\in V/W,
$$
Which easily implies that $U := {\rm range}(R)$ is complete (because $V/W$ is) and hence closed.

Furthermore, for $x \in V$, we let $y := R\pi x\in U$ and observe 
$$
\pi y = \pi R \pi x =\pi x
$$
and hence $x-y \in {\rm ker}\pi = W$, so that $x = (x-y)+y \in U +W$.

Finally note that $y \in U \cap W$ implies $y=R x$ for some $x \in V/W$ as well as $\pi y =0$ and hence 
$$
0=\pi y = \pi R x=x
$$
and thus $y = Rx = R0=0$, so that $U \cap W =\{0\}$.

Comment: I did intentionally leave that out, simply because I was looking for a general statement. However, I was not aware of the proof in the complete case. Thanks!